# How to serve static files over HTTPS

Tags: go, https, static-content

I have been scratching my head for way too long with this one - my issue is rather trivial however I cannot really figure it out myself: how does one serve static files over HTTPS in Go?

So far I have tried using both `HTTP.ServeFile` and `mux.Handle` with no particular success whatsoever.

```
func main() {
mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Add("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains")
    http.ServeFile(w, req, "./static")
})

cfg := &tls.Config{
    MinVersion:               tls.VersionTLS12,
    CurvePreferences:         []tls.CurveID{tls.CurveP521, tls.CurveP384, tls.CurveP256},
    PreferServerCipherSuites: true,
    CipherSuites: []uint16{
        tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
        tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
        tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
        tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
    },
}
srv := &http.Server{
    Addr:         ":8080",
    Handler:      mux,
    TLSConfig:    cfg,
    TLSNextProto: make(map[string]func(*http.Server, *tls.Conn, http.Handler), 0),
}
log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServeTLS("./server.rsa.crt", "./server.rsa.key"))

}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to create a https server. Are you using  `http.ListenAndServeTLS` instead of `http.ListenAndServe` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [http.ListenAndServeTLS](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServeTLS) to start an HTTPS server.

```
func main() {
    // Set up the handler to serve a file
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
        http.ServeFile(w, req, "./text.txt")
    })

    log.Printf("About to listen on 8443. Go to https://127.0.0.1:8443/")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":8443", "cert.pem", "key.pem", nil))
}
```

And to start an HTTPS server serving a directory with `FileServer`...

```
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":8443", "cert.pem", "key.pem", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))))
```

You can use [`generate_cert.go`](https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go) to create self-signed certificates for testing.

Comment: Not necessarily what I am after, I have updated the question with somewhat longer code. The problem is that I am using my custom mux and cannot throw any additional parameters to the ListenAndServeTLS method apart from cert.pem and key.pem.

Comment: @Maciej21592 Your code works for me, if I change `"./static"` to a file that exists. What problem are you having? Is it because `./static` is a directory, not a file?

Comment: Yes it is indeed a directory containing several javascript/css files.

Comment: @Maciej21592 And you're getting a 404 from the server? This is because `ServeFile` serves a single file.

Comment: I have managed to come around the issue using; 
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
mux.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs)) 
... the problem is that the file server still serves me the static resources using HTTP 1.1 instead of HTTPS :(

Comment: @Maciej21592 [It Works For Me™](https://gist.github.com/schwern/b982bf726220458a60724efd67cb795e). Perhaps you don't realize that HTTPS is HTTP encrypted with TLS? You will get the normal HTTP/1.1 headers, but now encrypted with TLS. If you connect with `curl -v` you'll see the TLS handshake and then the normal HTTP request/response follows.

Comment: Tested it now on the server and it works just fine, doing it locally is still a lot of pain though! Thank you for your effort put into helping me resolve the issue!